# ajax and php: how to select variables from database and insert in database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I really have never done this before and I am getting frustrated because I'm not sure how it fits together.  I have a function that I want to call my php (one php file selects info from a database and the second inserts into the database)... I need to use ajax in the way my site is setup but I don't know how to pass data from and to the php files.

In first .js file:

```
q1LoadVar();
```

This is my ajax function in second .js file that I have so far (not working):

```
//ajax code has been edited here since original post:

function q1LoadVar() {
alert("called"); //works!
$.get( "q1LoadVar1.php", function( data ) {

console.log(data); //nothing happens!
// alert(data); //nothing happens!

}, "json" );

}
```

And here is the code I have in q1LoadVar1.php that I want to select data back from and be able to populate a text area in my html:

```
/*works when I type this file path directly into the url; 
but the file is not communicating back to the ajax function on the 
.js file that is calling it*/ 

<?php   
$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini'); 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){  
echo mysqli_connect_error();  
}  

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("working from php!");</script>';

$query = "SELECT * FROM Game1_RollarCoaster";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$newRow[] = $row;
}

$json = json_encode($newRow);
echo $json; //works on php file directly!

/*while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[Q1_AnswerChoosen];
}*/

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Can someone help me understand how to make this all work together? Thank you, Kristen

Comment: Is there any kind of error in your console? Could be response error or PHP error as well. Try to include at the top of your PHP file ` error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. its possible that your response in console return what kind of error yoou're facing it.

Comment: You're missing VALUES for your INSERT. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html - *for one thing.*

Comment: Also, `mysqli_error($conn)` should be `mysqli_error($link)`

Comment: I edited the above question to concentrate on the ajax and the php the selects from the database. When I run the "q1LoadVar1.php" file - the php code works but of course it doesn't run when called with the above ajax.... nothing happens at all when I run the ajax... not sure how to test it..

Comment: So, where is your function call to `q1LoadVar` ? And you have syntax errors. Check your console(f12)

Comment: my function is: q1LoadVar(); I have checked this (with alerts within the function) and it calls it correctly.. it's just getting the ajax inside the function to work correctly... I checked with f12 in the console and I don't have any logged errors at all.

Comment: so the q1LoadVar(); function runs and the q1LoadVar.php file echos out the variable... I just don't know how to get ajax to call the php and how to pull the variable back into the ajax to do something with it upon "success".... please help...

Comment: Just by calling the function your ajax call is executed(check the network tab in your developer tools). You can also see the response in that tab. Furthermore, is your success callback executed? So, what is the output of `alert(output);`? Otherwise, add an error callback to see what kind of error you receive. And I would add some `try..catch` statements. In your JavaScript as well as in your PHP. ps. use @ with the name to notify someone.

Comment: ok, going to give it a shot... I will write back with my results

Comment: Guy - ok so I went to the network tab and nothing was showing there at all. On the original ajax code I had the alert(output) was not running. I changed the ajax in the above to be $.get instead of $.ajax ... so I'm still stuck in the same place with the ajax not working (the function is being run but either the ajax within the function is not running or it is not constructed correctly and for this reason not bringing anything back - the alert (data) is not working (also, I keep checking the .php code to make sure it works and when the file is called separately it does).

Comment: update: added alert on php page... of course when php file run direcly from url the alert appears, but it does not appear when the ajax trys to call the php file so the ajax function is not even calling the php page... and the files are in the same folder...

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe my problem is that I'm calling the ajax from within a function and it should be attached to an element....

Comment: I want to call my php script that locates specific variables in a database so that I can decide which elements on a page I want to "unhide".... so maybe ajax isn't the correct way to get the php to run.... but how do I run my query on the database and then get my page to read the results and do something with them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve post data from ajax in php with

```
$_POST['action']
//in your case will return: test
```

To return data to ajax you need to use **echo**

If the success: callback function doesnt get called try to remove `datatype: 'json'`

I also think that you need to echo `$newrow` instead of `$row`.

If this still doesnt work you can catch the error with the `error:` callback function to see what is wrong.

Try to start with a simple request and work from there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourphp.php",
        data: {simplestring: "hi"},
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and yourphp.php

```
<?php
$simplestring = $_POST['simplestring'];
echo $simplestring;
```

Comment: ok, going to give it a shot... I will write back with my results

Comment: Georg - I changed up the ajax request and made it a $.get instead so I don't have the datatype anymore (I copied the example in Jquery API).. but the ajax call with "get" doesn't appear to be working either... nothing comes back with the alert(data).. yet the php file when run separately echos out the correct information from the database. (BTW: I did change the $newrow thing like you suggested... I think that's closer to getting it to work... still missing something with the ajax request though to get it to work :(

Comment: update: added alert on php page... of course when php file run direcly from url the alert appears, but it does not appear when the ajax trys to call the php file so the ajax function is not even calling the php page... and the files are in the same folder...

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe my problem is that I'm calling the ajax from within a function and it should be attached to an element....

Comment: I want to call my php script that locates specific variables in a database so that I can decide which elements on a page I want to "unhide".... so maybe ajax isn't the correct way to get the php to run.... but how do I run my query on the database and then get my page to read the results and do something with them??

Comment: added a basic ajax example, this should work. try building from here and see where it goes wrong. Also if you want to execute the ajax when the page is loaded use jquery's document.ready

Comment: maybe that's not it... just tried putting the ajax onto a div I have: function q1LoadVar() {
$( "#popUp" ).ajax({ 
  method: "GET",
  url: "q1LoadVar1.php",
  dataType: "script"
});
 
} but got an error in the console: "Object doesn't support property or method 'ajax' "...

Comment: you still have the datatype specified ('json'). try removing it. Also you dont have to attach it to an element. you just need to call it.

Comment: oh, thanks for the response! I'm going to check it with your updated example now :)

Comment: no, didn't work... I put the new ajax and the new php file on the server: function q1LoadVar() {
alert("called!!!!!!");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Georg.php",
        data: {simplestring: "hi"},
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
        }
    });
} and here is the new php file code with an alert that works when I type the path directly in the url: <?php  
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("working from php!");</script>';
$simplestring = $_POST['simplestring'];
echo $simplestring;

?>

Comment: so the new code you put in didn't work... the ajax didn't even call the php file... what could that mean?

Comment: it works on my computer.. strange. Add error: callbackfunction to see what is wrong

Comment: Make sure that the php file is in the right folder. also check the console / resources (f12) look for errors

Comment: it worked! strange, the two files are in the same folder... but when I did the error:callback it was giving a 404 code that it couldn't find the file... so I put the absolute url into the pathing and it worked! so now I'm going to try putting my old php file into the mix to see what I can get... I will post the results/questions/success soon!

Comment: @ristenk1 Glad to hear that you made some progress

Comment: yay!! thank you so much for your help!!!!! I think once I was sure with your working model above I was able to modify it to what I needed :)